# heroku Could not generate key in Windows XP

Tags: facebook, heroku, ssh-keys

I am trying to program my first facebook app using heroku, but I can't get started. I am following the instructions heroku provides (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook), but I cannot generate the SSH public key. Here is what I'm seeing/doing:

```
heroku login
(enter credentials)
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? (press enter)
Generating new SSH public key.
 !    Could not generate key:
Bryan T Anderson@BRYAN ~
```

I have looked on several other forums and tried the following:

- tried the above commands in cmd.exe and in Git Bash
- created a .ssh directory (~/.ssh)
- tried "ssh-keygen -t rsa" AND "ssh-keygen -t rsa -C myemail@hotmail.com

One other strange thing I noticed is that when I "cd ~", and type pwd, it says I am in /c/Program Files/Java.   Not sure why it isn't /c/Program Files/Git.

Answer (score 0):

change directory to

C:\Program Files\Git\bin
and then run the command